# Apache 2.4 htaccess GeoIp redirect if else

Tags: apache, .htaccess, geoip

This not work.

```
<If "%{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} in { 'RU', 'BY', 'KG', 'KZ', 'TJ', 'MD', 'UA', 'RO', 'UZ' }">
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^$ en [L]
</If>
<Else>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^$ tr [L]
</Else>
```

GEOIP is installed and working in another rules without IF-ELSE statement.

```
<If "env('GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE') in { 'RU', 'BY', 'KG', 'KZ', 'TJ', 'MD', 'UA', 'RO', 'UZ' }">
```

This not working as well.